# Custom JMail delivery with properties from service

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I know this issue is old, but I didn't find any solution for SimpleMailMessage with properties added in the class and not in the xml. There is no exeption after my app starts, its simply not sending mail. The method CustomMailDeliveryImpl.sendMail()  is trigered from Controlller. I cant find a mistake.

```
@Component("CustomMailDelivery")
public class CustomMailDeliveryImpl implements CustomMailDelivery {

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomMailDeliveryImpl.class);

    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    private String username = "* * *@gmail.com";

    private String password = "* * *";

    private JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

    @Autowired
    public void setSender(JavaMailSenderImpl sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setEmployeeService(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    /**
     * @param from    - must contain address of sender,
     * @param to      - must contain address of target,
     * @param subject - must be included with short description,
     * @param body    - main message of mail.
     * @throws RuntimeException if any param is empty.
     */
    public void sendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String body) {

        // selecting settings from DB
        SystemSettingsModel settingsModel = employeeService.getSettingsByName("default");

        // defining settings
        sender.setHost(settingsModel.getSmtpServerAddress());
        sender.setPort(settingsModel.getSmtpServerPort());
        sender.setUsername(username);
        sender.setPassword(password);

        // defining SMTP properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.debug", "1");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);

        sender.setSession(session);

        // initiating mail
        SimpleMailMessage simpleMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        try {
            if (from != null && to != null) {
                if (subject != null && body != null) {

                    simpleMessage.setFrom(from);
                    simpleMessage.setTo(to);
                    simpleMessage.setSubject(subject);
                    simpleMessage.setText(body);

                    sender.send(simpleMessage);

                    logger.debug("Mail has been sent successfully");
                } else {
                    throw new MessagingException("Subject and message of mail is empty!");
                }
            } else {
                throw new MessagingException("Address of object and target is empty!");
            }
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated !!!!

Comment: No exception is thrown when you call the `sendMail()` method from your Controller?

Comment: check that your smtp server works...

Comment: @Sotirios, yes. When i call sendMail() nothing hapens.

Comment: @Tim Herold, i use gmail server. sender works with properties added in xml config.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to overcome this issue and I did found the solution! With this way? you can pass properties from page configuration or DAO Service!

```
@Component("CustomMailDeliveryImpl")
public class CustomMailDeliveryImpl implements CustomMailDelivery {

private EmployeeService employeeService;

private Transport transport;

private String username = "***@gmail.com";

private String password = "***";

private SystemSettingsModel settingsModel;

private Session session;

private MimeMessage message;

private InternetAddress fromAddress, toAddress;

private Properties properties;

@Autowired
public void setEmployeeService(EmployeeService employeeService) {
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
}


public void sendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String body) throws    SendFailedException {

    settingsModel = employeeService.getSettingsByName("default");

    // defining properties
    properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", settingsModel.getSmtpServerAddress());
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", settingsModel.getSmtpServerPort());
    properties.put("mail.smtp.user", username);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    // InternetAddress initialisation
    try {
        fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
        toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);

        // new Authenticator session
        session = (javax.mail.Session) Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);

    } catch (AddressException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    // executing mail sending
    try {
        if (from != null && to != null) {
            if (subject != null && body != null) {

                // defining message
                message = new MimeMessage(session);

                message.setFrom(fromAddress);
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
                message.setSubject(subject);
                message.setText(body);
                message.setSentDate(new Date());
                message.setHeader("MIME-Version" , "1.0" );
                message.setHeader("Content-Type" , "text/html" );

                // Transport initialisation
                if (transport == null) {
                    transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
                    if (!transport.isConnected())                            
                    transport.connect(settingsModel.getSmtpServerAddress(),
                       settingsModel.getSmtpServerPort(), username, password);
                }

                transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

            } else {
                throw new MessagingException("Subject and message of mail is empty!");
            }
        } else {
            throw new MessagingException("Address and target of mail is empty!");
        }
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    } finally {
        if (transport != null) try {
            transport.close();
        } catch (MessagingException ignore) {
        }
    }
}
```

}

It's working just perfect!!